# Futura font in Flex application

Tags: flex3, fonts

I'm developing a Flex application and wish to use Futura font to render text. My dev OS is Windows and so unlike Mac, the font does not come standard with the OS. I have downloaded and tried several different versions of Futura fronts from various websites but they give transcoding errors such as "Unable to transcode FuturaMDBold.ttf".

Any recommendations on reliable source for downloading / purchasing individual fonts?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. I've tried a dozen techniques and solutions. Flex, and by extension, Flash, is garbage. Don't waste your time on a compiler engineered to be *useless* unless you pay hundreds of dollars to the Adobe IDE Monopoly. :\

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [embed font](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/)?

Comment: Flex builder gives transcoding error and is unable to embed the font!